# Lots of attachments is causing slow load

Tags: images, attachments

I have a wordpress site with 400k unattached images. When I try to view any single attachment page it loads quite slow. Is there anyway to improve performance?

Comment: First thought is to index wp_posts table? I have no confirmation or backup to this though.

Comment: how do I index wp_posts table?

Comment: Might wanna take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002605/how-to-add-indexes-to-mysql-tables I haven't got a complete guide, though. It'd be amazing if someone would comfirm my theory on indexes.

Comment: Might wanna repair and optimize too? Edit: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-optimize/

Comment: Indexing doesn't seem to help since I found out that wordpress already has index implemented. I don't have post revisions since I mainly upload images on it. Can't really optimize the database since it's InnoDB

Comment: Ah. I did not realize this. Have you considered caching?

Comment: Try debug/profiler plugin, [Query Monitor](http://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) for example, and see if it tells you what _exactly_ is being slow.